# How to refresh collection on client?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I loading data on client from server:

```
var context = new WordsDomainContext();
context.LoadWords();
```

And I using my collection *context.Words* on client as I need. It's working good.
But I want to refresh my *context.Words* for some reasons. When I call again `context.LoadWords()` new record just append to current collection.

I tried use `MergeOption context.LoadWords(null, MergeOption.OverwriteCurrentValues, null)` but no effect.

How I can clean my *Words* collection and load new data from server?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to call this before you use the `LoadWords()`:

```
context.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, context.LoadWords);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply refresh your collection on client from the database using :

```
collection.Load(MergeOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

b.t.w - collection is an `EntityCollection` type.